# Repeated issue: Error Reading JObject from JsonReader

Tags: c#, asp.net, parsing, json.net, restsharp

I've got a weather app that I continually receive weather related information in JSON format. So far, I'm using Newtonsoft to retrieve and parse the response. Unfortunately, every now and then I get an error which really is confusing.

The code runs fine, but after a few hours, my application throws an exception and displays this error:

`Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Path '', line 0, position 0.`

> > JSON structure

`{
"weather": {
    "city": "Seattle"
    "temperature": "20"
    "degrees": "C"
    },
}`

> > Code

```
  public static JObject GetWeather(string url)
        {
            var client = new RestClient(url);

            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

            var response = client.Execute(request);
            var content = response.Content;

            var result = JObject.Parse(content);

            return result;
        }
```

When I want to retrieve the city, temperature or degrees, this is how I do it =>

`var city = result["weather"]["city"].ToString()`,

`var temperature = result["weather"]["temperature"].ToString()`,

`var degrees = result["weather"]["degrees"].ToString()`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Where in your code is the exception thrown from?  It sounds like maybe the server is sometimes returning a response which does not contain JSON for some reason.  Do you have to authenticate with this server?  Could it be that your session is timing out?  It doesn't look like you are checking to see if the request was successful before attempting to parse the content.  If you're using RestSharp there should be an `IsSuccessful` boolean on the `response` object, or there should be a `StatusCode` you can look at.  I would also check to make sure the content is actually JSON.

Comment: You are very right. I might have to check for `statuscode` to make sure that it is successcul. And yes, I am using Restsharp. I should have indicated this in my post.